# How to have a camera access with card view in android?

Tags: java, android

I'm having a problem with camera access with the use of card view in android. Every card when being selected does open the camera.

Here's the code:

```
private CardView card1, card2, card3, card4;

@SuppressLint("MissingInflatedId")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_shape_layout);
    Objects.requireNonNull(getSupportActionBar()).setTitle("Select a Shape");
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    //Action Bar Color
    ActionBar actionBar;
    actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    ColorDrawable colorDrawable = new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#782DD8"));
    actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(colorDrawable);

    //CardView buttons
    card1 = (CardView) findViewById(R.id.c1);
    card2 = (CardView) findViewById(R.id.c2);
    card3 = (CardView) findViewById(R.id.c3);
    card4 = (CardView) findViewById(R.id.c4);

    card1.setOnClickListener(this);
    card2.setOnClickListener(this);
    card3.setOnClickListener(this);
    card4.setOnClickListener(this);

    }
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (v.getId() == R.id.c1 || v.getId() == R.id.c2 || v.getId() == R.id.c3 || v.getId() == R.id.c4) {
        // Check camera permission
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M &&
                    checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, REQUEST_CAMERA_PERMISSION);
        } else {
            // Camera permission already granted, open camera
            openCamera();
        }
    }
}

private CameraDevice cameraDevice;
private CameraCaptureSession cameraCaptureSession;
private CaptureRequest.Builder captureRequestBuilder;

private void openCamera() {
    // Get the camera manager

    CameraManager cameraManager = (CameraManager) getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);

    try {
        // Get the first camera id
        String cameraId = cameraManager.getCameraIdList()[0];

        // Check camera permission
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M &&
                    checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, REQUEST_CAMERA_PERMISSION);
            return;
        }

        // Open the camera device
        cameraManager.openCamera(cameraId, new CameraDevice.StateCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onOpened(@NonNull CameraDevice camera) {
                cameraDevice = camera;
                // Start the camera preview
                startPreview();
            }

            @Override
            public void onDisconnected(@NonNull CameraDevice camera) {
                cameraDevice.close();
                cameraDevice = null;
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(@NonNull CameraDevice camera, int error) {
                cameraDevice.close();
                cameraDevice = null;
                Log.e(TAG, "Failed to open camera: " + error);
            }
        }, null);

    } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Failed to access camera: " + e.getMessage());
    }
```

I've tried implementing the code "Intent" to open the camera on the next layout but it still doesn't work. When one of the card view is press, the camera should open.